# How to use symlinks in React Native project?

Tags: react-native, npm, symlink

The symlink support is still not officially available in react-native https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/1.

It's actually possible to use symlinks in the package.json with npm (not yarn)

```
{
  "name": "PROJECT",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "my_module1": "file:../shared/my_module1/",
    "my_module2": "file:../shared/my_module2/",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.5",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "24.7.1",
    "jest": "24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
},
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Although we will get `my_module1` does not exist in the Haste module map

To fix this we could do before a metro.config.js (formerly rn-cli.config.js)

```
const path = require("path")

const extraNodeModules = {
  /* to give access to react-native-firebase for a shared module for example */
  "react-native-firebase": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react-native-firebase"),
}
const watchFolders = [
  path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/my_module1"),
  path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/my_module2"),
]

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    extraNodeModules
  },
  watchFolders,
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work anymore on react-native 0.59 The app is reloading, but changes in the source code are not reflected in the app. Anyone has a clue to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few years working on this, we found a reliable way using yarn.

Add your local dependencies with are inside a folder file:../CompanyPackages/package e.g:

```
// package.json
"dependencies": {
  "local-package": "file:../CompanyPackages/local-package"
}
```

Use a custom metro.config.js

```
const path = require("path")
const { mapValues } = require("lodash")

// Add there all the Company packages useful to this app
const CompanyPackagesRelative = {
  "CompanyPackages": "../CompanyPackages",
}

const CompanyPackages = mapValues(CompanyPackagesRelative, (relativePath) =>
  path.resolve(relativePath)
)

function createMetroConfiguration(projectPath) {
  projectPath = path.resolve(projectPath)

  const watchFolders = [...Object.values(CompanyPackages)]
  const extraNodeModules = {
    ...CompanyPackages,
  }

  // Should fix error "Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault"
  // See https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/7#issuecomment-508129053
  // See https://dushyant37.medium.com/how-to-import-files-from-outside-of-root-directory-with-react-native-metro-bundler-18207a348427
  const extraNodeModulesProxy = new Proxy(extraNodeModules, {
    get: (target, name) => {
      if (target[name]) {
        return target[name]
      } else {
        return path.join(projectPath, `node_modules/${name}`)
      }
    },
  })

  return {
    projectRoot: projectPath,
    watchFolders,
    resolver: {
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
      extraNodeModules: extraNodeModulesProxy,
    },
  }
}

module.exports = createMetroConfiguration(__dirname)
```

Comment: For people using Expo this is how you generate the metro file: `npx expo customize metro.config.js`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and found [haul](https://github.com/callstack/haul).

1. Follow haul [getting started](https://github.com/callstack/haul#getting-started) instructions.
2. Add your local dependencies with `file:../` e.g:

```
// package.json
"dependencies": {
  "name-of-your-local-dependency": "file:../"
}
```

3. reinstall node_modules with `yarn --force`
4. Start the development server by `yarn start` (haul will replace your start script)
5. Run `react-native run-android` or/and `react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [yalc](https://github.com/wclr/yalc). Yalc will simulate a package publish without actually publishing it.

Install it globally:

`npm i -g yalc`

In your local package:

`yalc publish`

In the application:

`yalc add package-name && yarn`

After you made some changes to the package, you can just run

`yalc push`

and it will automatically update every app that uses your local package

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me

Comment: still works 11/2023. this is the right answer

Comment: sad that I can only upvote this answer once :(

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers I found worked for me and it seems symlinks are not going to be supported anytime soon (see: https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/1), so I had to do it manually.

I am using `onchange` npm package and running that in my local package: `onchange 'dist/**/*.js' -- cp -R ./dist ../../app/node_modules/@author/packagename`

That worked for me to achieve development and testing, while not breaking anything for production releases. I hope this can save my peers a few headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Could never get my own environment working using any other suggestions, but found a hack that works well (though not ideal) that can be easily set up in just a few lines of code and without changing your RN project configuration.

Use `fs.watch` for changes recursively in the directory where you're working on your library, and copy the updates over whenever there's been a change:

```js
import fs from 'fs'

const srcDir = `./your-library-directory`
const destDir = `../your-destination-directory`

fs.watch("./src/", {recursive: true}, () => {
  console.log('copying...')
  fs.cp(srcDir, destDir, { overwrite: true, recursive: true }, function() {
    console.log('copied')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Only two things are required.
1.yarn --force
2.yarn start

then select android for running option